# Do all subsets of $Q$ which are bounded from above have a greatest upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis

*Is the following statement true or false?*

Every subset of the rational numbers $Q$ which is bounded from above by the
number $2$ has a greatest upper bound $c ∈ Q$.

---

Wouldn't all subsets also be bounded by 2 and thus they are all bounded from above and thus they have a supremum?

or

Since the only restriction is that $c ∈ Q$ it could be a number larger than $2$ which is a contraction to the fact that $2$ is the upper bound of the set?

Comment: Do you mean LEAST upper bound (supremum)? The greatest upper bound would be $+\infty$.

Comment: @Bungo Ah... I didn't notice that :P I'm guessing then it's false

Comment: Well, if you really meant greatest upper bound, then it's true, provided that you accept $+\infty$ as a bound (e.g. if working in the extended real number system).

Answer (score 1):

I’m assuming that the statement should read *has a **least** upper bound* $c\in\Bbb Q$. If you really mean what you wrote, the statement is obviously false.

Consider $A=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q^2<2\}$. $A$ is bounded above by $2$, but it has no least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$: its least upper bound in $\Bbb R$ is $\sqrt2$, which is not in $\Bbb Q$. If $c$ is a rational number less than $\sqrt2$, there are members of $A$ greater than $c$, and if $c$ is a rational number greater than $\sqrt2$, any rational number strictly between $\sqrt2$ and $c$ is a smaller upper bound for $A$.

Comment: The canonical example.